# htaccess | not looking in the right location for js

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to write a htaccess file that will allow for `/example/1/profile` to look for a JavaScript file within `/example/`. Currently on Internet Explorer 11 it is looking for `/example/1/file.js` whereas realistically it should be looking for `/example/file.js`.

This needs to be done inside of the `.htaccess` file as the setup that the website currently has.

I know there is a way in which you can redirect 404 to `/example` however this is resulting in a 200.

Is their a way I can say in the htaccess file that if it is `.js` `.css` to look in `/example`?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

For a little but more information, my current htaccess is like this

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /example/index.php [NC,L]
```

It is for php because the php echos a `file_get_contents` of the `index.html` which is an Angular project.

So I need this htaccess to be the following logic

If the file is a `.js` or `.css` then rewrite the location to `/example` else rewrite the location to `example/index.php`.

The reason this is happening is because I am doing a format which has the ID as a second parameter and for some reason this is interfering with the way that the URL is structured for the js, css.

I imagine this line is what is breaking it...

`RewriteRule ^(.*) /example/index.php [NC,L]`

Comment: Add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/example/" />`

Comment: I have added this but doesn't seem to be working which is the reason why I have to do it like this

Comment: My bad, it seems to have worked now... I didn't include the `/>` at the end of the tag. Could this be the reason why?

Comment: Well, I wrote `<base href="/example/">` can you put as the answer so I can accept please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comments to answer. This appears to be problem due to relative links.

To fix, you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/example/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.